Import data using XML from Tally Server/cloud
I have a tally server that runs on a remote server (say 114.112.102.19) and a tally server instance running on it and connectivity exposed on port 9000. How do I get a list of companies on my tally server if, say, my server login username and password is: admin and test123
I can type in the IP in the browser, and it redirects me to a login page, so the static IP is okay. The application is running on the cloud instance. I tried the following XML, but it did not run.
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CUSTOMCOMPANYCOL</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
           <STATICVARIABLES>
               <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
               <USERNAME>admin</USERNAME>
               <PASSWORD>test123</PASSWORD>
           </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CUSTOMCOMPANYCOL">
                        <TYPE>COMPANY</TYPE>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>NAME, STARTINGFROM, BOOKSFROM, BASICCOMPANYFORMALNAME, EMAIL, PINCODE, INCOMETAXNUMBER, GSTREGISTRATIONNUMBER, STATENAME, GUID</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>


What do you mean by "Application is running on the application"? And when you say "it did not run", what were the symptoms?

Apologies, it was a typo. I meant "the application is running on the server"
